# Chrome tab.create and tab.getSelected

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have some problems to pass message from background page to my content_script.js. I hope someone can point out where i am wrong.

**background.html**

```
//in a function
function myFunction() {
    chrome.tabs.create({"url":"myurl","selected":true},function(tab){
    updateTab(tab.id);
    });
}

//update Created new tab
function updateTab(tabId){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
        makeRequest(tab.id);  
    });}
//make request
function makeRequest(tabId) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabId, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell); 
    });
}
```

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    else
      sendResponse({}); // snub them.
  });
```

**manifest.json**

```
"permissions": [
        "tabs","notifications","http://*/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
        "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }],
```

My problem is the request from background.html has never been passed to the content_script.js. I think there must be some problems about the sequence of creating new tab and selecting that tab, but i do not know how to fix this.
Thanks.

EDIT: 
There is what i have done so far.

**background.html**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
        var tabId = tab.id;
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {   
           validate(tab.url,tabId);
        });
    });
    function validate(url,tabId) {
        var filter = support(url);
        if(filter!=null) {
            getHTML(tabId,url,filter);
        }
        else{
            var notification = webkitNotifications.createHTMLNotification(
              'notification.html'  // html url - can be relative
            );
            notification.show();
            setTimeout(function(){
                notification.cancel();
            }, 10000);  //10 sec
        }
    }
function getHTML(tabId,url,filter) {
        console.log("request"); 
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabId, {action:"getHTML"}, function(response) {     
            var html = response.html;
            console.log(html);
            var taburl = ("some thing on server");  
            chrome.tabs.create({"url":taburl,"selected":true}, function(tab){
                var tabId = tab.id;
                chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo){
                    if(changeInfo.status == "loading"){
                            console.log("loading");
                  }
                  if(changeInfo.status == "complete"){
                          chrome.tabs.onUpdated.    removeListene(arguments.callee);                    
                        updateTab(tabId,url,filter,html);

                  }
                });
              }); 
            });
    }
function updateTab(tabId,url,filter,html) {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabId, {action:"updateTab"}, function(response) {
                //submit form
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {code: 'document.getElementById(\"hiddenbutton\").click();'});
        });
    }
```

**content_script.js**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var action = request.action;
    console.log(action);
    if(action == "getHTML") {
        var html = document.body.innerHTML;
        console.log(html);
        sendResponse({html:document.body.innerHTML});
    }
    else{
    //do update on page from server
    sendResponse({});
    }
});
```

It works as i expected, but there are still some points that i do not understand, espically removing listener **chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListene(arguments.callee);**. I hope if someone can have a chance to have a look and correct me if any thing is wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The background.html can be simplified to:

```
//in a function
function myFunction() {
    chrome.tabs.create({"url":"myurl","selected":true}, function(tab){
        makeRequest(tab.id);
    });
}

//make request
function makeRequest(tabId) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tabId, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
        console.log(response.farewell); 
    });
}
```

If it still doesn't work correctly then it might be because the tab hasn't finished loading (log [tab.status](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab) in the chrome.tabs.create callback to check if this is true). There are two solutions for this, or you add an listener to [chrome.tabs.onUpdated](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) while filtering for this tab id or you make the [tab send the request](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-sendRequest) instead of background.html.