# google chrome extension get new tab ID 

Tags: google-chrome-extension

how can i get the new created tab ID after chrome.tabs.create? 
and what if it was more that one tab create in the same time?

thank you.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5817355/3441905

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok found the solution

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function(tab){
    alert("new tab "+tab.id);
});
```

Answer (score 9):

The `chrome.tabs.create` API has the callback function that returns an `object` containing the new tab details

```
chrome.tabs.create({"url":url},function(newTab) {
console.log(newTab.id);
});
```